# Text slide in on hover CSS

Tags: css, hover, slide

I want the text `Along came` to slide in when mouse hovers over `the wolf`.
But the position of `the wolf` should not change. `Along came` should simply slide in and fade in from the left to complete the sentence.

```css
.main {
  width: 100vw;
  text-align:center;
}

.addText {
  display: none;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
  transition: .5s;
}

.link:hover .addText {
  display: inline;
  color: red;
  transform: translate(-10px, 00%);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="link">
      <span class="addText">Along came </span>
      the wolf
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an idea where you can make the element `width:0` so it doesn't affect the other element:

```css
.main {
  text-align:center;
}
.link {
  display:inline-block; 
}
.addText {
  display:inline-block; /* inline-block so we can set a width */
  width:0;
  white-space:nowrap; /* keep text one line */
  direction:rtl; /* change direction so the text overflow on the left */
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
  transition: .5s;
  transform: translateX(20px); /* put the value you want here */
  pointer-events:none; /* to avoid the hover on the text, remove to see the difference */
}

.link:hover .addText {
  color: red;
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="link">
      <span class="addText">Along came </span>
      the wolf
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also do only the translation in case you want the text to take the space:

```css
.main {
  text-align:center;
}
.link {
  display:inline-block; 
}
.addText {
  display:inline-block; 
  color: rgba(255,255,255,0);
  transition: .5s;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.link:hover .addText {
  color: red;
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="link">
      <span class="addText">Along came </span>
      the wolf
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe make `<div class="link">` inline so the whole line isn't sensitive to the hover?

Comment: Thanks @TemaniAfif. How can we fix this so that the mouse over only works when the mouse is over `the wolf`. Currently it slides it when the mouse hovers the empty region as well.

Comment: @amars I fixed it by adding inline-block to .links

Comment: @TemaniAfif hey yes. saw that and the new update. But it's still not working in the above snippet. Still flies in when mouse is on the empty region where `Along came` will come and stop. I thought it might be this site, but same on the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/aLdo4h16/

Comment: @amars check again the first snippet, made another update